# How to parse highly nested json data that represents arithmetic expression

Tags: python, json, loops, recursion

I just want to write a Python program which can takes arithmetic expressions in JSON format, parses and evaluates the answer.

Each operators like PLUS takes at least 2 arguments, MINS and TIMES take exactly 2 arguments, but the checks are not relevant

I am able to read the JSON object but the hard part is that i don't understand how can I use recursion to parse the nested object.

Any guidance/help/ideas would be helpful

I was thinking that recursion would be a great thing to use here, but I don't understand what the base cases should be and how to treat the different type of operations (plus, minus, times)

```
{
    "root": { "description": "Result should be 8",      
        "plus": [{
            "times": [{
                "int": 2
            }, {
                "int": 3
            }]
        }, {
            "minus": [{
                "int": 4
            }, {
                "int": 2
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Object two that gives me more problems

```
{
    "root": { "description":" it evaluates to 12.",     
        "plus": [{
                "plus": [{
                        "plus": [{
                                "plus": [{
                                        "plus": [{
                                                "int": 2
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "int": 2
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "int": 2
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "int": 2
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "int": 2
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "int": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried with the code below, but it doesn't work properly with nested expressions:

```
def operation():    
   val = 0    
   with open("expression1.json") as complex_data:
       data = complex_data.read()
       z = json.loads(data)

       data = z['root']    
       for op in data:
           if op == 'description':
               pass
           elif op == 'plus':
               return sum(element[k] for element in data[op] for k in element)
           elif op == 'minus' or op == 'times':
               if len(data[op]) != 2:
                   raise ValueError('2 elements expected if operation is minus >or times')
               nums = [element[k] for element in data[op] for k in element]
               if op == 'minus':
                   return abs(nums[0] - nums[1])
               else:
                   return nums[0]*nums[1]
           else:
               raise ValueError('Invalid operation')
```

Sorry it is my first time using stack overflow and I don't understand how to format the code

Comment: You're on the right track. You want a function like `eval_obj` that evaluates the object to depth 1, calling itself on any nested expressions. You would start by passing this function your root object. Iterate over that. If one of the "ops" is a nested expression, use recursion to evaluate that expression `n = eval_obj(op)` and append the result to a list of numbers. In the end, you'll be left with some set of numbers and you just need to apply the top-most operation (like `sum`) and return the result.

Comment: But what should the recursive function return. How is the recursive function going to stop?

Comment: The function returns the result (a number) of the expression it's evaluating. Taking your first example formatted as strings:

`eval_obj('(2 * 3) + (4 - 2)')` ->
`return eval_obj('2 * 3') + eval_obj('4 - 2')` ->
`return eval_obj('2') * eval_obj('3')` and `return eval_obj('4') - eval_obj('2')` ->
`return 2` and `return 3` and `return 4` and `return 2`

Comment: The recursion "stops" when a simple expression like `int` is evaluated. This does not recurse, but just returns the value of the int. Hope it helps.